# How can I suspend/kill a child process from the child using keyboard?

Tags: c, readline

In my shell program I am reading from the keyboard via Readline:

```
rl_bind_keyseq ("\\C-c", readline_func); // ctrl + c

int readline(...){
    // handle keyboard controls
}
```

This works when I'm in my outside loop, but once I get a long command such as 'wc' where I'm in my child process, ctrl+c is not being picked up, I get ^C in the terminal. The keystrokes are defined before I forked.

I'm interested in killing the process, so when I'm running 'wc' and ctrl+c is detected, I'll kill(pid, sigint)

my parent process is waiting for the child via:

```
waitpid(pid, &child_status, 0);
```

Also am I able to call kill from within the child to get it to stop/pause?

Comment: you can absolutely do that by using the signal handlers for ctrl+c and kill() command